# SQL: How to know if a LEFT JOIN returned a row?

Tags: sql, join

Simple problem. I have a simple SQL as thus...

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2, XXX
FROM table1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN table2 as b
    ON b.Key1 = a.Key1
```

What can I put in the 'XXX' above to say something like "does table B exists?".

ie: `EXISTS(b) AS YesTable2`

I am hoping there is a simpler solution than just using CASE...END statements.

Thanks

Comment: if the table doesn't exist your query won't run

Comment: Yes it would. It's a LEFT JOIN not INNER. Surprised people gave you kudos for that obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)(b.Key1, 'XXX') Or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) for checking against multiple values for the first non null value.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any column from `b` that is not allowed to be NULL. If there is a NULL there, the record does not exist. If there is a value there, the record does exist. If every column in `b` is allowed to be NULL (rare: you should always have something that's not nullable in the primary key) you'll have to build an expression that mimics the JOIN conditions.

Comment: Precise answer I required, but the COALESCE response won it! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

> I am hoping there is a simpler solution than just using `CASE...END` statements.

Your guess is spot-on: you can use `CASE...END` to compare `b.Key1` to `NULL`, like this:

```
SELECT
    a.Col1
,   a.Col2
,   CASE WHEN b.Key1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as YesTable2
FROM table1 AS a
  LEFT JOIN table2 as b
    ON b.Key1 = a.Key1
```

Comment: Thanks but I was trying to avoid CASE.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if a record exists, I would suggest using `exists` in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT a.Col1, a.Col2,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 b ON b.Key1 = a.Key1)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as ExistsInTable2
FROM table1 a;
```

This version will guarantee that you do not get duplicated rows if there are multiple matches in the two tables.

Comment: Sorry but that has a huge cost in performance by using both CASE *and* EXISTS() in the one statement. I was trying to find a solution other than using CASE, no matter what the condition in the WHEN dictated.

Comment: What is the issue with `case`?  And `exists` is often more efficient than a `left join`, especially in this case where the `join` might multiple the number of rows.